# Why does the "retard" command on the Airbus sometimes continue after the thrust levers are already at idle?

Tags: airbus-a320, airbus

There are many examples where the PF will place the thrust levers at idle and the "retard" command will continue sounding. Here are some examples: [1](https://youtu.be/0NVeOQwxopM?t=453) and [2](https://youtu.be/WrDgesrIYc8?t=81). *Note* that I am not referring to the singular "retard" command that will sound between 20 and 10 ft regardless of the A/THR status or thrust lever position ([here](https://youtu.be/rYY9MaTInDQ?t=195) is an example of that).

Answer (score 2):

Simply because the callout always occurs at 20 ft radio height, regardless of the position of the levers. Therefore, idling the levers also does not interrupt the callout. The callout is only a reminder to the pilots, not an order according to the A320 Flight Crew Training Manual:
[image]

Comment: But what determines how often your hear the RETARD callout? In the linked YouTube videos, you can hear it 5 times, 3 times and once respectively.

Comment: @Bianfable Probably the model of aircraft. Some aircraft only call it once.

Comment: "Note that I am not referring to the singular 'retard' command that will sound between 20 and 10 ft regardless of the A/THR status or thrust lever position..." I believe that is what your answer is referring to. The question is why it will sound even after 20ft with the levers at idle (as seen in the videos).

Comment: @CharlesNicholson I suspect the callout simply repeats because the levers in the videos you posted are not yet fully in the idle position.

Comment: @stefanlinden Did you watch the videos? That's the main point of the question, they are at idle. This only seems to occur on the A320 (and not any other Airbus airplane).

Comment: To answer your question, multiple `RETARD` callouts tend to happen when the descent rate is very low, so on especially smooth landings.